# Woocommerce renewal orders stuck on Pending Payment

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce, orders, payfast

I'm having an issue with my Woocommerce store regarding the subscriptions.

Everything works perfectly except for the renewal orders getting stuck on 'Pending Payment' even after the payment has gone through successfully. This needs to change to 'Processing' or 'Completed' after the payment has gone through.

I'm using Payfast as a payment gateway.

I've tried:

http and https in the return URL.
Contacted Payfast (They say their systems are fine).
Increased PHP limits.
Updated plugins.

Comment: Can you give more detail on your subscription product is your subscription parent product set to virtual? this will help debug the issue. 

if your parent product is not virtual it may not allow the child order to auto complete

Comment: @BradHolmes Holmes The product is in fact set to virtual

Answer (score 1):

This is most likely due to your passphrase. it is the most common issue with WooCommerce orders that aren't updating.

Do you have a passphrase set on your PayFast account?
If so, make sure you set the same passphrase on your WooCommerce backend. Else, make sure to leave the passphrase section empty on your plugin backend.

The best way to see why your orders aren't updating is to check the PayFast.log file which will be generated if you have logging enabled on the WooCommerce plugin. It should give you an indication of what is going on behind the scenes.